# How can I restrict users to only edit their data with Linq To SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql

**Background:**
I've been working on a small proof-of-concept web application in ASP.NET 4.0 with C# and I've been using Linq To SQL because it's quick and easy. I've now got to restrict one user from seeing another user's data in the same database. So I've added an 'account' column to most of my tables and I want to check that the current user is a member of the same account as the data they are viewing/editing before allowing them access.

**One possible solution I'm not really happy with:**
I could simply but painfully go through all of my Linq To SQL queries and add an if statement to do the check like this:

```
MyDataContext DB = new MyDataContext();
//get the current user's information from the DB
USER myUser = DB.USERs.Where(j => j.USR_EMAIL == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
//get the object to edit
MYOBJECT myObject= DB.MYOBJECTs.Where(j => j.ID == IdFromQueryString).FirstOrDefault();
//compare the user's account with the object's account they are now trying to view
if(myUser.AccountID == myObject.AccountID)
{
    //display the object
}
else
{
    //display error message
}
```

This would be a lot of work to do throughout the entire application and not to mention the repetition and opportunity for mistakes. It will also be painful to maintain and if I forget to add this for a query I will leave a security hole open.

**The Question:**
Is there a way to do this once for each table and it automatically checks every time I do a query with Linq To SQL? OR Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should had used the [Repository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) pattern and not access directly `Contest.Users`, but always access `Repository.Users`. Then you could had change the repository to expose `Users` as `from u in InternalContext.Users where u.AccountId = currentAccountId select u` thus enforcing the scope. Coincidentally this technique is [called a scope in Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope)...

The next best thing is to use [`DataLoadOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534361) to associate a lambda filter with your entities, see [How to: Filter at the DataContext Level (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386915.aspx). You would need to add this to every context you create. Again, refactoring the code to obtain the data context from a method (or better, implement a repository pattern...) would help a lot.

Finally you could go on the back end and implement this via updateable views and [`context_info()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but I would strongly discourage this.

PS. I hope you made the `account_id` the leftmost key in every clustered index on the tables, and made the entity `id` primary key non-clustred, did you? Your performance will tank otherwise.

Comment: I just realized the answer I was going to give was essentially the same as the first part of your answer but I was going to emphasize how you could have your Repository return IQueryable(s) so that further filtering could be done efficiently at the database level.  The Repository pattern is such a nice pattern to use with IQueryable(s); thanks for reminding me of that.

Comment: You are a champion. No I haven't indexed as you describe, but I will now. The Repository pattern sounds good - can you recommend any resources that will help me get started with it (an example would be nice)? Also, thanks JayC for mentioning IQueryables - I hadn't heard of these before

Comment: @Dean: everything is LINQ is basically an IQueryable. As for the repository pattern, the topic is more complex and it webs together with concepts like TDD (test driven development) and IoC (Inversion of Control). Start with [Walkthrough: Using TDD with ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847525.aspx). There was a good tutorial on Channel9, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, do you have AccountID's available for both objects? If so, is there any reason why you can't join them on their Accountid?

```
var query = from o in DB.MYOBJECTs.Where(w => w.ID == IdFromQueryString)
            join u in DB.USERs.Where(w => w.USR_EMAIL = User.Identity.Name) on o.AccountID equals u.AccountID
            select o;
```

Comment: Yes I have AccountId's available for both objects. Thanks for your more succinct code, it's definitely better than what I have! However, my ideal solution would be one where I can manage this code in one place

Answer (score 0):

Two possible approaches:

- Use stored procedures to access the data rather than direct queries; give the users permission only to these stored procedures (ie no general read access to the database) and have the stored procedures enforce the access restrictions.
- Proxy all access to the database through a separate service - the service is then the only thing with general access to the database and can enforce the access restrictions.

These aren't fundamentally too dissimilar from your current strategy of wrapping every query, but may be easier to manage.

Comment: Don't forget sql functions... those can be combined in arbitrary (and relatively efficient) sql queries, unlike stored procs. I don't know how well that translates to linq-to-sql, though.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by a separate service, can you give me an example?

Comment: Have a separate process which is the only thing which can access the database and talk to that process via some form of RPC. This gives you very strong separation between the concerns, which has some advantages: for example, even if your main program has a security flaw, you won't compromise access to the database (a flaw in the service is a different question, of course). I suspect this is probably too heavyweight for your use case, though.

Comment: OK, yeah that is a bit of an overkill for my particular application, but something to keep in mind for other projects. Thanks!